# Writtin a personal budget script on Python; how to work with categories/subcategories? How to link files?

Tags: python, pandas, database, csv

My idea is to create a .csv file (e.g. data.csv) with all the elements that could potentially be present in my expenses detailing to which category and subcategory they belong, as well as its corresponding reference price (e.g. 'house insurance' would belong to 'house' category and 'services' subcategory.

Then have another .csv file (e.g. expenses.csv) where I daily introduce the expenses as they come up, but just writing the date and name of the expense and having Python (maybe through Pandas) read from the base .csv file to which category and subcategory it belongs, and writing the outcome to a dataframe where these daily expenses would be appended.

My question is; how do I tell Python to take each element in expenses.csv, look in data.csv to which category and subcategory they belong as well as their price, and include these values in a third file (e.g. expenses_total.csv)?

I'm sure this is nothing complicated for most of you, but I'm still a noob with Python and still struggle when it comes to interconnecting values from different files.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Consider presenting some code, so that we could refer to the problem directly, or at least provide some divide-and-conquer attitude towards the problem you've described.  Nonetheless you might want use `pandas` module to create `pd.DataFrame()`s with the data you have and then join datasets together with `df.merge()` method. The resulting data frame could be easily exported to csv file.